# Chef Kitchen: Error pullling a kitchen box for sles 12

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I am trying to converge a kitchen sles box. But I keep getting the following error. I was able to converge a centos-7 so I dont think anything is wrong in my configuration.

```
---- Begin output of vagrant up --no-provision --provider virtualbox ----
STDOUT: Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'sles-12-sp3' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'sles-12-sp3' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: sles-12-sp3
[K
STDERR: An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /root/besclient/.kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/remove-sles-12-sp3/sles-12-sp3
```

Here is my kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-7
  - name: sles-12-sp3
    driver:
      gui: false

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - besclient
    attributes:

  - name: remove
    run_list:
      - besclient::default
      - besclient::remove
    attributes:

/usr/local/packer build -only=virtualbox-iso sles-12-sp3-x86_64.json
virtualbox-iso output will be in this color.
```

I tried building using packer but got the following error.

```
==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying Guest additions
    virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying: file:///usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying ISO
    virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying: file://./packer_cache/SLE-12-SP3-Server-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso
    virtualbox-iso: Error downloading: open /root/bento/sles/packer_cache/SLE-12-SP3-Server-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso: no such file or directory
==> virtualbox-iso: ISO download failed.
Build 'virtualbox-iso' errored: ISO download failed.

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> virtualbox-iso: ISO download failed.

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are bento definitions for SLES, I don't see any images on Vagrantcloud. I'm guessing we can't redistribute the OS a la RHEL and Windows. You might have to build and host them yourself. See https://github.com/chef/bento#proprietary-templates for some very minimal details.

Comment: I already tried this. Updating the question with error received there.

Comment: As the instructions say, you'll need to modify the paths to the ISO because the ISO is not public and we cannot distribute it to you. You'll need to get a copy from SUSE somehow.